# unknown type name '__uint64_t'

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I have recovered old developments, (embedding proC) that do not compile anymore following a migration (oracle 11g to 12c).

Note: The data has been anonymised.

Old environment:

```
Linux <NOMDELAMACHINE> 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 13 00:51:26 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Oracle 11g 
gcc : 
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
Copyright © 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Ce logiciel est libre; voir les sources pour les conditions de copie.  Il n'y a PAS GARANTIE; ni implicite pour le MARCHANDAGE ou pour un BUT PARTICULIER.
```

New environment:

```
Linux <NOMDELAMACHINE> 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jan 14 10:36:03 EST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Oracle 12c
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)
Copyright © 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Ce logiciel est libre; voir les sources pour les conditions de copie.  Il n'y a PAS GARANTIE; ni implicite pour le MARCHANDAGE ou pour un BUT PARTICULIER.
```

In the old environment, when we compile, there are no problems.

On the other hand, when we compile on the new environment, we get the following problem:

```
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:340:0, 
                 from /usr/include/sys/wait.h:30, 
                 from /tmp/compilC/inc/LIBPERSO.h:39, 
                 from FichierC.c:27:

/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:33:3: erreur: unknown type name ‘__uint64_t’
   __uint64_t xstate_bv; 
   ^ 
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:177:3: erreur: unknown type name ‘__uint64_t’ 
   __uint64_t xstate_bv; 
   ^ 
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:178:3: erreur: unknown type name ‘__uint64_t’ 
   __uint64_t reserved1[2]; 
   ^ 
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:179:3: erreur: unknown type name ‘__uint64_t’ 
   __uint64_t reserved2[5];    ^

make: *** [FichierC] Erreur 1
```

I compared the sigcontext of both environments and actually, I do not have the same installed:

old enviro sigcontext:

```
struct sigcontext

{

  unsigned short gs, __gsh;

  unsigned short fs, __fsh;

  unsigned short es, __esh;

  unsigned short ds, __dsh;

  unsigned long edi;

  unsigned long esi;

  unsigned long ebp;

  unsigned long esp;

  unsigned long ebx;

  unsigned long edx;

  unsigned long ecx;

  unsigned long eax;

  unsigned long trapno;

  unsigned long err;

  unsigned long eip;

  unsigned short cs, __csh;

  unsigned long eflags;

  unsigned long esp_at_signal;

  unsigned short ss, __ssh;

  struct _fpstate * fpstate;

  unsigned long oldmask;

  unsigned long cr2;

};
```

sigcontext new enviro :

```
struct sigcontext

{

  __uint64_t r8;

  __uint64_t r9;

  __uint64_t r10;

  __uint64_t r11;

  __uint64_t r12;

  __uint64_t r13;

  __uint64_t r14;

  __uint64_t r15;

  __uint64_t rdi;

  __uint64_t rsi;

  __uint64_t rbp;

  __uint64_t rbx;

  __uint64_t rdx;

  __uint64_t rax;

  __uint64_t rcx;

  __uint64_t rsp;

  __uint64_t rip;

  __uint64_t eflags;

  unsigned short cs;

  unsigned short gs;

  unsigned short fs;

  unsigned short __pad0;

  __uint64_t err;

  __uint64_t trapno;

  __uint64_t oldmask;

  __uint64_t cr2;

  __extension__ union

    {

      struct _fpstate * fpstate;

      __uint64_t __fpstate_word;

    };

  __uint64_t __reserved1 [8];

};
```

The make file used for compilation:

```
CC=gcc    

# Repertoire des fichiers include ".h"     
# ------------------------------------

INCDIR=/tmp/compilC/inc     
INCDIRBADS=/tmp/compilC/inc     
SRCDIR=/tmp/compilC     
OBJDIR=$(SRCDIR)/obj    

ECHO=$(ORACLE_HOME)/bin/echodo

CFLAGS=-I$(INCDIR) -I$(INCDIRBADS) -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/precomp/public -DPRECOMP -Dextension -undef -O3 -Wall -v 


# Fichiers de declarations ".h" a inclure     
# ---------------------------------------     
INC=\

 $(INCDIR)/header1.h\     
 $(INCDIR)/header2.h\     
 $(INCDIR)/header3.h\     
 $(INCDIR)/header4.h\     
 $(INCDIR)/header5.h\     
 $(INCDIR)/header6.h\     
 $(INCDIR)/header7.h\     
 $(INCDIR)/header8.h\     
 $(INCDIR)/header9.h

all: FichierC

# FichierC.o     
# ---------

$(OBJDIR)/FichierC.o:\     
   $(SRCDIR)/FichierC.c $(INC)     
    @$(ECHO) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $(SRCDIR)/FichierC.c
```

Currently, I do not know how to orient my research.

I would say that the problem comes from the version of the library that is installed incorrectly but I'm not sure and being the master of the environment (root account) I can not do the actions I want to test.

Do you have any leads / ideas to unlock me?

Can I recover the library "sigcontext.h" and embed it in the project at the address of my INCDIR?

UPDATE == 
I updated my code to more anonymous, so i can i give you more :

Make :

```
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:340:0,
                 from /usr/include/sys/wait.h:30,
                 from FichierC.c:8:
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:33:3: erreur: unknown type name ‘__uint64_t’
   __uint64_t xstate_bv;   ^
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:177:3: erreur: unknown type name ‘__uint64_t’
   __uint64_t xstate_bv;   ^
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:178:3: erreur: unknown type name ‘__uint64_t’
   __uint64_t reserved1[2];   ^
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:179:3: erreur: unknown type name ‘__uint64_t’
   __uint64_t reserved2[5];   ^
FichierC.c: In function ‘test’:
FichierC.c:20:4: attention : cette fonction retourne l'adresse d'une variable locale [-Wreturn-local-addr]
    return(ach_DateHeure);    ^
make: *** [FichierC] Erreur 1
```

FichierC :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char ach_DateHeure[500] = {' '};

char *test(void)
{ 
    char ach_DateHeure[500] = {'0'};

   return(ach_DateHeure);
}
```

So the problem is on line

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

Comment: Did you `#include <stdint.h>` ?

Comment: In the header1.h i got :
/*   Librairies standards */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

But i see no difference when i make.

I have to includ in make , or something ?

Comment: What's on line 27 of `FichierC.c`?  And post the entire contents of `/tmp/compilC/inc/LIBPERSO.h`.

Comment: Check `/usr/include/signal.h` - it should have an include like `#include <bits/types.h>` to include the header file that defines `__uint64_t`, and it should have that *before* the `#include <bits/sigcontext.h>`. Verify all that, and double check that none of these files were modified after installation.

Comment: The error messages do not fit any of the  headers given.

Comment: Check /usr/include/signal.h
I got 
#include <bits/types.h>

Before 
# include <bits/sigcontext.h>

They weren't update since install.

Comment: Did you verify that `bits/types.h` actually defines `__uint64_t` ? And that there are no `#if`s conditionally disabling needed parts ? Etc. Ie. track down the reason that the `__uint64_t` type is unknown at line 33 in `sigcontex.h`.

Comment: in /usr/include/bits/types.h i got :

/* Fixed-size types, underlying types depend on word size and compiler.  */
typedef signed char __int8_t;
typedef unsigned char __uint8_t;
typedef signed short int __int16_t;
typedef unsigned short int __uint16_t;
typedef signed int __int32_t;
typedef unsigned int __uint32_t;
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef signed long int __int64_t;
typedef unsigned long int __uint64_t;
#elif defined __GLIBC_HAVE_LONG_LONG
__extension__ typedef signed long long int __int64_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned long long int __uint64_t;
#endif

Comment: I believe `__uint64_t` is a violation of the standard. The `*_t` type names are reserved, iirc.

Answer (score 0):

So on my machine, __uint64_t (with the leading underscores) is defined only in
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h

And is used only in
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/* (including sigcontext.h)
and
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/*

/usr/include/signal.h includes:

```
#include <bits/types.h>
#include <bits/signum.h>
```

then much later:

```
/* Get machine-dependent `struct sigcontext' and signal subcodes.  */
# include <bits/sigcontext.h>
```

These are the places I suggest to check for a library inconsistency.

Also check your code is not including  directly?

Comment: I got what you say in my signal.h

Comment: And does bits/types.h define it?

Comment: In /usr/include/types.h i got :
'
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef signed long int __int64_t;
typedef unsigned long int __uint64_t;
#elif defined __GLIBC_HAVE_LONG_LONG
__extension__ typedef signed long long int __int64_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned long long int __uint64_t;
#endif
'

Comment: Track that down to bits/wordsize.h, and perhaps you have `__ILP32__` defined somehow? All thos underscores get turned into bold randomly.

Comment: I look at __WORDSIZE and i find it in : /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h

I m in x86_64, so wordsize = 64

Comment: Sorry for bad comment :(
Didn't know how to do the correct '. 

I check in a program the value of wordsize : (printf("%d",__WORDSIZE) and i get 64.